# Netsuite print individual statement

Tags: netsuite

I want to edit the print of Individual Statement in

> Transaction>Customers>Individual Statement.

but I am unable to get  the form/pdf Layout.

Comment: If you have Advanced PDF/HTML templates enabled, there is a standard Customer Statement template that you can edit.

Comment: I can edit that template.thanks. Now i am setting dynamic data in the pdf but it is not getting set. Also not setting in WYSIWYG mode

Comment: What do you mean not getting set?

Answer (score 1):

I was printing Standard statement pdf/html template. Instead I should have printed Standard Multi-currency Statement pdf/html. Now i can edit it and print it.